# How to print more than one String using grep and sed?

Tags: linux, sed, grep, command

Imagine i have a log file or a text file like below

```
16 Dec 2014 11:20:00 [INFO] com.example.Test.java PlaneName: JetAirways360 This flight just cleaned up
16 Dec 2014 11:22:01 [INFO] com.example.Test.java PlaneName: JetAirways360 This flight is in queue
16 Dec 2014 11:23:02 [INFO] com.example.Test.java PlaneName: JetAirways360 This flight passengers loaded
16 Dec 2014 11:24:03 [INFO] com.example.Test.State.java PlaneName: JetAirways360 This flight ready to take off
16 Dec 2014 11:25:00 [INFO] com.example.Test.State.java PlaneName: JetAirways360 This flight took off
17 Dec 2014 11:25:00 [INFO] com.example.Test.java PlaneName: JetAirways360 This flight returned back
```

Now imagine i this log file is fully filled off lot of flight information. it is heard to find a particular flight information. Now i would like to grep to see following details

```
16 Dec 2014 11:20:00 This flight just cleaned up
16 Dec 2014 11:22:01 This flight is in queue
16 Dec 2014 11:23:02 This flight passengers loaded
16 Dec 2014 11:24:03 This flight ready to take off
16 Dec 2014 11:25:00 This flight took off
17 Dec 2014 11:25:00 This flight returned back
```

How to do this using grep and sed command?.

Comment: This worked for me `grep 'JetAirways360' lofFile | sed -e 's/\(.*\) \[INFO.*JetAirways360\(.*\)/\1 \2/g'`. Added detailed explanation below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep 'JetAirways360' lofFile | sed -e 's/\(.*\) \[INFO.*JetAirways360\(.*\)/\1 \2/g'
```

To explain this.

1. First i am grepping all the log entries which has JetAirways360.
2. I am using sed. each bracket (.*) is what i am trying to get from log. \1 is for first (.*) and \2 for second (.*). Its like print statements for string value i cut from original line.

Details:

1. sed regular expression should contain between this s/ /g
2. \1 and \2 are the print statements for (.*).
3. (.*) is represented as (.*). Escape sequence
4. s/(.*) [INFO This Explains Put all characters into the parenthesis till you see [INFO (i have put escape character \ for [ and hence [INFO). That's how i got Date selected and  printed using \1
5. [INFO.*JetAirways360(.*) This explains, After seeing [INFO start ignoring till you see JetAirways360. After which put all remaining character into parenthesis. That's how i got log message selected and  printed using \2

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/JetAirWays360/s/(.{21}).{54}/\1/p' file
```

This saves the first part of the file in a back reference and replaces a portion of the remaining file with it.

Comment: It is slightly dependent from the flyid, but it is very nice solution!

Comment: It would be nice to explain what is{21} and {54} here. If i can understand the command i can modify for different situations. Thanks

Comment: @RaviKrishnaP the `.{21}` means the space occupied by 21 characters which in the example you supplied is `16 Dec 2014 11:20:00 ` for the first line.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the explanation. This character position is an assumption and may not hold good all the time. 21 character yes it holds correct but not 54 character. Check 5th and 6th line. (I just updated it to avoid assumptions. Sorry should have done this first).

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to do with `awk` file

```
awk -F" [[]|JetAirways360 " '{print $1,$3}' file
16 Dec 2014 11:20:00 This flight just cleaned up
16 Dec 2014 11:22:01 This flight is in queue
16 Dec 2014 11:23:02 This flight passengers loaded
16 Dec 2014 11:24:03 This flight ready to take off
16 Dec 2014 11:25:00 This flight took off
17 Dec 2014 11:25:00 This flight returned back
```

Comment: I would never though about putting the search pattern in the FS! Good!

Comment: Could you please explain me the command here. It will help me to understand the usage. Thanks

Comment: @RaviKrishnaP This `" [[]|JetAirways360 "` mean use `[` or `JetAirways360 ` as field separators, then print field number `1` and `3`.  The  `[` needs to be in the group characters like this to work `[[]`.  This  `|` means or.  Just normal `regex` within `FS`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/\[.*JetAirways360/ s///p' YourFile
```

should do your job based on your sample

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this with sed the command below also works.

```
   sed 's#\([[:digit:]]\{2,2\}.*[[:digit:]]\{2,2\}:[[:digit:]]\{2,2\}:[[:digit:]]\{2,2\}\).*PlaneName.*JetAirways360 \(.*\)#\1 \2#g' 'my_log_file'
```

It marks the first two digits in the line up to the up to the flight time and remembers it. sed then searches the line for JetAirways360 and after this name it marks the remainder of the line. The two patterns are then combined.

**Using grep and cut**

Another easier trick to do this without using grep or sed is using "cut" (even though this might no pertain to answering your question)

```
cut -d ' ' -f1-4,9- 'my_log.txt'
```

from field (column in this case) 1 to 4 is printed and then field 9 onwards

results using "cut"

```
16 Dec 2014 11:20:00 This flight just cleaned up
16 Dec 2014 11:22:01 This flight is in queue
16 Dec 2014 11:23:02 This flight passengers loaded
16 Dec 2014 11:24:03 This flight ready to take off
16 Dec 2014 11:25:00 This flight took off
17 Dec 2014 11:25:00 This flight returned back
```

Note: this just cuts the columns you need and output no grepping nor "sedding" is involved.

You can also use grep for a Plane name which will print all lines with the Plane name and then use "cut"

**example**

```
grep "JetAirways36" 'my_log.txt'|cut -d ' ' -f1-4,9-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print if s!.INFO.*Name: JetAirways360!!' file
```

If you prefer a new command `flygrep`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n 
BEGIN{ $fl = shift;}   
print if s!.INFO.*Name: $fl !!
```

Usage: `flygrep JetAirways360 file`